# How to Use OOP effectively to implement Interfaces for displaying different Output formats

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have to implement an output display module in a java application. It has three output formats, HTML, CSV and .txt.

**The input formats are of 2 types:** either `ArrayList` or `HashMap`.

I have to implement this using OOPS effectively and defining interfaces for each type of output functionality. I want to know if there is a better way to implement this.

**The pseudo code for what I have tried so far is:**

```
OutputDisplayInterface 
{

 public void TextDisplay();
 public void CSVDisplay();
 public void HTMLDisplay();
}

TextDisplayInterface
{
public void maptotext();
public void listtotext();
}
TextDisplayClass implements TextDisplayInterface{
  \\method implementations
}
CSVDisplayInterface
{
 public void maptocsv();
 public void arraylisttocsv();

}
 CSVDisplayClass implements CSVDisplayInterface{
  \\method implementations
}
HTMLDisplayInterface
{
public void maptoHTML();
public void arraylisttoHTML();

}
HTMLDisplayClass implements HTMLDisplayInterface{
  \\method implementations
}
OutputDisplayClass implements OutputDisplayInterface
{
 public void TextDisplay(){
 TextDisplay t = new TextDisplayClass();
 t.maptotext();
 t.listtotext();

}

public void CSVDisplay(){
CSVDisplay t = new TextDisplayClass();
t.maptocsv();
t.listtocsv();

}
 ....
}
```

If I call `TextDisplay()` in the main function, both the methods `maptotext()` and `listtotext()` will be called, when in fact I want only one of them to execute as per the input data type(i.e  `hashmap` or a `list`) .

Comment: According to my knowledge I think this is a quite good approach.

Comment: First of all, almost none of it will compile, because you're missing `TextDisplay` and `CSVDisplay` types. Second, Java already has a working OOP solution for this, it's called `toString()`.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If yes, have you read the [guidelines for those](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering from polymorphism point of view:

```
OutputDisplayInterface 
{
 public void TextDisplay();
 public void CSVDisplay();
 public void HTMLDisplay();
}
```

I don't think the above would be useful as displaying `text`, `csv` and `html` are the different implementations. You won't achieve polymorphism with this. I would suggest the below (pseudo-code) (I'm assuming the input would be passed in.)

This is the contract for **any display element**. It has a *display* method taking a `List` and a `Map`.

```
DisplayInterface {
    display(ArrayList list); //Or just List to be better
    display(HashMap map);  //Or just Map to be better
}
```

There would be three implementations of the above

```
TextDisplay {
    display(ArrayList list) {..}
    display(HashMap map) {..}
}
CSVDisplay {
    display(ArrayList list) {..}
    display(HashMap map) {..}
}
HTMLDisplay {
    display(ArrayList list) {..}
    display(HashMap map) {..}
}
```

**Note:** Using raw types like `List`, `ArrayList` should be avoided. Use a generic type based on your usecase.

**Usage:**

```
DisplayInterface displayInterface = new TextDisplay();
displayInterface.display(list); //This invokes the method that takes a list.
//OR
displayInterface.display(map);  //This invokes the method that takes a map.
```

Comment: You took bad desing and made it little better, but it's still bad design. The main idea here is to create an abstraction for input and output that uses single interface. The processing will be same for all combinations. A client then will use single interface with single method. The configuration(format etc) is hidden in the concrete implementation of input.

Comment: @Rob Are you referring to having multiple methods one for each type (List and Map)?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
interface Output {
    String text();
}

interface HtmlListOutput implements Output {

    private final ArrayList list;

    //ctor

    @Override
    public String text() {
        //list to html text
    }

}

interface HtmlMapOutput implements Output {

    private final HashMap map;

    //ctor

    @Override
    public String text() {
        //map to html text
    }

}

//proxy/delegate class
class HtmlOutput implements Output {

    private Output origin;

    public HtmlOutput(ArrayList list) {
        this.origin = new HtmlListText(list);
    }

    public HtmlOutput(HashMap map) {
        this.origin = new HtmlMapText(map);
    }

    @Override
    public String text() {
        return origin.text();
    }

}
```

Same with CSV and .txt.